# Access: How to match/relate records to each other within the same field?

Tags: microsoft-access

In my Access Database is a table with project information, the ID is 'projectnumber'. I want to be able to match/link/relate different projectnumbers (all stated in the same field) to each other.

So when I open project 1 in a form, I want see the projectnumbers of projects that are related to project 1 , for example project numbers 2, 5 and 6. And when I open project 2, I would like to see the projectnumbers 1, 5 and 6. In the form, I would like to add new 'relationships'.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to make this happen. Do I need to create a new table (or just one field) that gives the projects that are related to each other a 'relationship ID'? Or can this be solved by a selfjoin?

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by Andy G is perfect if you have a master/slave relationship (ie: one main project, and several related sub projects).

But if you have a equal relationship where any record can relate to any number of other records, then you can to create what I call a "Link Table", where you have 2 fields:ID of record A, and ID of record B

Then, in the Form where you enter or review your record, you can create a subform with this Link Table to add links.

Note : You can also create a macro to make sure that for every A-B record in the Link Table, you also have a B-A record, or simply do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but, yes, a **self-join**.

- Add a new field to the table such as `MainProject`. Make sure it has the same data-type as the `ProjectNumber` field;
- Go into the relationships window and Add the table a second time. Drag and drop from `MainProject` of the first copy to `ProjectNumber` of the second copy;
- Double-click the join line and choose **Enforce Referential Integrity**. This will ensure that you cannot assign the `MainProject` an id which isn't already an existing `ProjectNumber`.

When you build a form which is used to create new records for this table, add a `ComboBox` and set its `RowSource` to a sql-statement that lists the ProjectNumbers (and perhaps other fields) form the table. Set its `ControlSource` to `MainProject`.

Note, however, that if you are creating a new project and this project's id will also be used as the main-project's id then it requires a little more effort. You would need to save the current record, and `ReQuery` the combobox before this new id will show in its list. You might want to use a button to achieve this with code. Manually, you can press `Shift-Enter` to save the current record, then click into the combobox and press **F9** to requery it.

However, if there are other details that are relevant to this main-project that aren't already in the table then, yes, you should create a new table to keep these details - specifically, that is, information that is ONLY relevant for main projects.

If you only need the ProjectNumber (of the main project) then the self-join as described above will suffice.